# How to create a conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius in java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-loops

The code should output ***a table for Fahrenheit and Celsius***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit\tCelsius");
    System.out.println("=======================");
     for(int temp = -45; temp <= 120; temp += 5) //for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d       |", temp);
            double sum = (temp + (9.0/5.0)) * 32;   
            System.out.printf("%5d", (int) sum );
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, i figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: They are all good answers. Hard to accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create a conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius in java

The most important step IMHO is to understand the problem before ever thinking about coding.

Wikipedia is a good start and searching for Celsius it give us:

> [°C] = ([°F] − 32) ×  5⁄9

In Java that would be something like:

```
celsius = (fahrenheit -32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
```

I think it is best to do that in a separate method so it is easier to test it:

```
public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
    double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    return celsius;
}
```

Note 1: it is worth testing this method before going on - two significant temperatures are:

- 32°F  ==  0°C  (melting point of ice)
- 212°F  ==  100°C  (boiling point of water)

so just do something quick & dirty like:

```
System.out.println("32 == " + fahrenheitToCelsius(32));
System.out.println("212 == " + fahrenheitToCelsius(212));
```

much better, maybe a bit to heavy in that simple case, is to use some framework like JUnit.

Note 2: for creating the table do as posted in the question, but only one `printf` to take advantage of having the format together at one place (obviously after calling above method):

```
System.out.printf("%5.0f | %5.1f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
```

Note 3: caution with `5/9` - in Java that is interpreted as integer division and would result in zero!

*(above code is just a sample and was not tested or debugged*

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes:

- Remove cast to `int` (as it makes the value lose precision)
- Use ".1f" in `printf` (as you need to print decimal number and not int)

Below should work:

```
System.out.printf("%10.1f", sum );
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Thank you so much.  i was trying the .1d and made it more complicated. Is there a way to structure the whole output to look a lot nicer. The output of the Celsius column looks a little strange.

Comment: Change `%.1f` to `%10.1f` and you will see the output aligned. I have updated that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the decimal format class

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

int numberToPrint = 10.234;
DecimalFormat threePlaces = new DecimalFormat("##.#");  //formats to 1 decimal place
System.out.println(threePlaces.format(numberToPrint));
```

Should print:

```
10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make output result looks like table, you have to use [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

I rewrote your snippet, a little bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(System.out);

    formatter.format("%-20s\n",      "---------------------------");
    formatter.format("%-10s %12s\n", "| Fahrenheit |", "Celsius |");
    formatter.format("%-20s\n",      "---------------------------");

    for (int farValue = -45; farValue <= 80; farValue += 5) {
        double celValue = (farValue + (9.0 / 5.0)) * 32;

        formatter.format("| %10d | %10.0f |\n", farValue, celValue);
    }
    formatter.format("%-20s\n", "---------------------------");
}
```

The output snippet looks exactly like ***a table***:

```
---------------------------
| Fahrenheit |    Celsius |
---------------------------
|        -45 |      -1382 |
|        -40 |      -1222 |
 ...
|        -30 |       -902 |
---------------------------
```